# How to skip relationship if it data does not exist?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a `Event` and a `Invitation` models, with a relationship between them: an event could have many invitations.

I am trying to show only the events which have invitations, if not, just skip the event.

My `Event` model:

```
class Event extends Model
{   
    public function invitations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Invitation::class, 'event_id') ?? [];   
}
```

I tried to use `?? []` if the relationship does not exist, returning an empty array is not working.

Here is my view:

```
@if ($event->invitations != null)
    @foreach ($event->invitations as $event)
        <h5>{{ $event->email }}</h5>
    @endforeach
@else
    <h5>Not Found</h5>
@endif
```

It is not going through the `else` statement.

How should I write it to go into the `else` statement when `$event->invitations` does not exist?

Comment: @TimLewis I don't think the `?? []` will cause any issues, it'll just never get called. `$this->hasMany` will *always* return something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned result of the `invitations()` method is a collection, so when you do `$event->invitations != null`, it will always be `true`, even if there is no invitation for a particular event (an empty collection is different of `null`).

I rather suggest you to check the size of the collection in your condition:

```php
@if ($event->invitations->count())
    @foreach ($event->invitations as $event)
        <h5>{{ $event->email }}</h5>
    @endforeach
@else
    <h5>Not Found</h5>
@endif
```

Or, the shortcut one:

```php
@empty ($event->invitations)
    <h5>Not Found</h5>
@else
    @foreach ($event->invitations as $event)
        <h5>{{ $event->email }}</h5>
    @endforeach
@endempty
```

Or even shortest:

```php
@forelse ($event->invitations as $event)
    <h5>{{ $event->email }}</h5>
@empty
    <h5>Not Found</h5>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only get events with invitations, you can use [`has`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$events = Event::has('invitations')->get();
```